# Adding a user to a group and a group to an Active Directory user

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using the code below and it works perfectly. I note that in this code a user is added to a group determiner. I want to know if there is any code that does the reverse, that is, add a group to a specific user.

```
public void AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn) {

try
{
    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
    dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);
    dirEntry.CommitChanges();
    dirEntry.Close();
}
catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
{
    //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing.

You're probably thinking of the [`memberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-memberof) attribute, but that is a [linked attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/linked-attributes) to [`member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-member). That means that the values you see in `memberOf` just tell you which groups have that user in its `member` attribute. The `memberOf` attribute cannot be directly modified.

Other examples of linked attributes are [`manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-manager) and [`directReports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-directreports), and [`managedBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-managedby) and [`managedObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-managedobjects), and others.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a C # code to include a user who is in a child domain to a group with universal scope but who is in another parent domain

Comment: If both domains are in the same AD forest, then there is no difference - you add the DN of the user to the `member` attribute of the group.